# Dual booting Ubuntu with LVM and FDE & Windows 10 on separate hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption, lvm

So I am planning on dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 on my desktop. Ubuntu as my main OS for everyday tasks, learning and dev stuff, and Windows just for gaming.

I want to install Ubuntu on my NVME SSD and Windows on my regular SSD. They are each 1TB in size. I also would like both drives to be encrypted, Ubuntu with LUKS and LVM and Windows with Bitlocker.

From the stuff I read so far there seem to be 2 methods for this.

1. Installing Windows, unplugging the Windows drive then installing Ubuntu and using the UEFI boot menu to boot into the desired OS.
2. Installing Windows, then install Ubuntu leaving the drive connected. Boot menu is handled by GRUB.

Most of the people seem to say that the second method is better, but one would have to manually partition the drive in the Ubuntu Live system during the installation. I have not been able to find a proper guide to do this with LVM and full disk encryption and since I am still kind of a newbie to Linux I am worried about breaking my drive.

Some people said to simply create a single encrypted LVM partition formatted as ext4 while others said to also create an unencrypted boot partition and also one for the boot manager.

Which method would you recommend? And if you recommend the second method as well, could you provide me with the proper instructions on how to partition the drive during the install?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I do not think grub can boot Windows with UEFI Secure boot on, or if encrypted. Better to disconnect each drive for install. You may have to reset UEFI boot setting as UEFI often forgets boot entry if drive removed. But many also find Windows, but not Ubuntu when reconnected. Just be prepared with both Ubuntu live installer flash drive & Windows repair flash drive. You should always have both for current installs anyway. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the link! I think I will install Windows and encrypt it, then disable secure and fast boot and check if everything still works. I think I will leave the drive connected for the first try, since GRUB should still pick up Windows and manage the operating systems. 
Going through it more tonight and will start the install tomorrow, hopefully everything works out! Will post an update tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that I worried about nothing and people make it sound more complicated than it is. Here is how it worked for me:

1. Secure erase both my SSD and NVME drives with Parted Magic
2. Install Windows on SSD
3. Turn on Bitlocker
4. Boot Ubuntu Live
5. Select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"
6. Select LVM and encryption
7. Select NVME drive
8. Install!

You can leave secure boot on in the BIOS. I just disabled Fast Boot. When you reboot the system you will see the GRUB boot menu, showing you both Ubuntu and Windows as boot options.